# using a lablel in .word directive

Tags: assembly, mips

So I was hoping the output would be 17, which is the value stored in the address of num2.
I am trying to reach it through the address of num1. The output it gives me is of an address of some sort.
My question is how do I reach the value of num2 through the .word label in num1?
Thanks

```
.macro print_int (%x)
li $v0, 1
add $a0, $zero, %x
syscall
.end_macro

.data 
num1: .word num2
num2: .word 17

.text 
.globl main

main:                                   
la $t1, num1
lw $t1, 0($t1)

Print: # print to consule
print_int($t1)

li $v0, 10                      # Exit program
syscall
```

Comment: num2 is an address when used in the way you have it with num1 .word num2.  basically thats what you told it to do.  I would read up on the assembler language (tool specific, I assume this is gnu assembler) to see what other choices you have when using labels in that way.

Comment: You could put 2 labels on the same address, like `num1:` ; `num2: .word 17`.  Or you could use `.equ num1, 17` to define assemble-time constants for use with `li` instead of putting constants in memory at all.

Answer (score 1):

OK, Got it, it's basically a pointer to a pointer, so just added the lw again and it worked as expected.

```
.macro print_int (%x)
li $v0, 1
add $a0, $zero, %x
syscall
.end_macro

.data 
num1: .word num2
num2: .word 17

.text 
.globl main

main:                                   
la $t1, num1
lw $t1, 0($t1)
lw $t1, 0($t1) 

Print: # print to consule
print_int($t1)

li $v0, 10                      # Exit program
syscall
```